# How to get SQL query into LINQ form in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-3.5

How can I convert the following SQL queries into LINQ query form in C#, .NET 3.5 code:
1)

```
select COUNT(distinct Skill_Name) 
from Table1  
where Department = 'ABC' and  Skill_Name is not null
```

2)

```
select distinct location, country from Customer where  Customer_Code ='1001';
```

Comment: See my asnwer's edit for second query

Comment: @sukmar for respect accept answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
var query = from entry in dbContext.Table1
            where entry.Department == "ABC" && entry.SkillName != null
            select entry.SkillName;

var count = query.Distinct().Count();
```

Or using extension method syntax, in one go:

```
var count = dbContext.Table1
                     .Where(entry => entry.Department == "ABC" && 
                                     entry.SkillName != null)
                     .Select(entry => entry.SkillName)
                     .Distinct()
                     .Count();
```

As shown by mesiesta, you *can* combine query expressions with calls not supported within query expressions, but I *tend* to assign the query expression to an intermediate variable... I personally find it clearer, but use whichever you (and your team) prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I want to add as columns in an exisitng datatable these unique skillNames which resulted from the above query. How??

Comment: @sukumar: If you just want the distinct names, get rid of the `Count()` call at the end. You can count the number of results when you've fetched them down to the datatable.

Comment: Hi, Assume the above query results count as 2 and next I want to add these two skillNames as columns in a existing datatable . How??

Comment: @sukumar: As I've said, you wouldn't use the `Count()` call there. I don't know about transferring into an *existing* `DataTable`, but you can use the LINQ to DataSet extension methods to create a *new* `DataTable` from a query result. See [DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
 int count = (from p in Table1
              where p.Department == "ABC" && p.Skill_Name != null
              select p.Skill_Name).Distinct().Count();
```

For second query you can use this

```
 var query= (from p in Customer
             where p.Customer_Code=="1001"
             select new { Location=p.location ,Country=p.country}).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi, Assume the above query results count as 2 and next 
I want to add these two skillNames as columns in a exisitng datatable . How??

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain it more detailed?

Comment: Ok, I get what you want. I don't hear anything about it, but I guess, you can't add columns to your table via LINQ. You can update your table's rows, but adding collumns seems like a not work of LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

you can use linqpad to convert to linq and lambda expressions

Comment: Hi, Pls help me how to get a linQ query for this SQL Statement:

select distinct location, country from Customer where   Customer_Code ='1001';

Comment: var query = (from q in customer
                         where q.customer_code == "1001"
                         select new { Location = q.location, Country = q.country }).Distinct();